apt-key deprecation fix is causing or revealing a temporary failure resolving the domain during geoblacklight installation
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an AWS server. I am trying to get geoblacklight installed, but it hasn't been updated in the past decade and I have been running into many issues. This is my first time using Linux in some years and I don't remember much at all. Here is the original script for installation (originally for use with vagrant):
wget -qO- https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/gpg.key | apt-key add -

echo "deb https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/suite/v46/ubuntu/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opengeo.list

apt-get update
apt-cache search opengeo
apt-get -y install opengeo-server

This gave me a deprecation error, so I looked up some solutions and replaced the first line of the script with wget -qO- https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/gpg.key | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gpg.key which didn't give an error until I called apt-get update where it gave the following output:
Hit:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]                          
Hit:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]                                      
Ign:5 https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/suite/v46/ubuntu trusty InRelease                                           
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages [293 kB]             
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 Packages [250 kB]                 
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease                                       
Ign:5 https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/suite/v46/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Ign:5 https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/suite/v46/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Err:5 https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/suite/v46/ubuntu trusty InRelease                                                                                                                                          
  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.boundlessgeo.com'
Fetched 796 kB in 7s (106 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/suite/v46/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.boundlessgeo.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I also tried wget -qO- https://apt.boundlessgeo.com/gpg.key | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/gpg.key as suggested by the article I found, but this did not fix the issue.
I also tried echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null to see if it was a DNS issue, to no avail. Should I permanently change my DNS? Is there something else going on here? Is the repo even still available, and how come I was able to get the original script to work in Ubuntu 16.04.3 with vagrant if so?
Note: it is also possible that the vagrant script didn't work and I completely missed it, but I doubt that this was the case since all of the other build issues from the other scripts---such as bundler and ruby being too outdated to install---caused fatal errors that canceled the entire build.
I imagine that something similar would've happened with geoblacklight, but I could be wrong.
By the way, I did all of this with root and tried with sudo before each command as well, in case that is important to mention.

It is not likely you will get 10 year old software to install on Ubuntu 20.04, as for Ubuntu 16.04 that is 10 year old software. There have been many release since then.

I don't think this is anything to do with apt-key - it looks like boundlessgeo.com is no longer up, possibly because the owner got acquired - see for example What Happened to Boundless Geo?

@steeldriver Thank you, I was afraid of that. Since there are a ton of databases that still use GBL, is there a way to get around this? It seems that GBL is just built off of boundless geo but is still running. I believe the Princeton University map library is still built off of GBL, for example. I am not sure how old that database is though, and I guess if it is older than 4 years they could've just installed GBL before the merge.
